# NFS permissions with groups

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have host A with users root and bob (who is a member of group 'root').  A's exports file offers /test directory for RW with no_root_squash.  The /test directory has 770 permissions and /test/t1 has 664 permissions.

I have host B with users root, and bob.  fstab is setup to mount A:/test to /mnt/test and that works fine.  The root user can do anything on on /mnt/test/t1.  And bob can read and write anything on /mnt/test.

But, bob can not read or write /mnt/test/t1  Why?

I tried adding bob to the 'root' group on B but that didn't make a difference.  bob has id 1000 on both hosts